# In Postgres, how can I round the return of extract epoch

Tags: postgresql

psql (9.6.7, server 11.3) on linux

Given this simple table...

```
dvdb=> select * from delme;
        start_dt        |         end_dt         
------------------------+------------------------
 2020-03-01 00:00:00-05 | 2020-03-03 12:34:56-05
(1 row)
```

I want the number of hours, rounded to the nearest tenth of an hour, of the time delta.  I can get this far...

```
dvdb=> select extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/3600) from delme;
 date_part 
-----------
 60.582222
(1 row)
```

But can't seem to round....

```
dvdb=> select round(extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/3600),1) from delme;
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select round(extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/3600),1...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
dvdb=> 


dvdb=> select round(cast(extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/3600) as float),1) from delme;
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select round(cast(extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/36...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
dvdb=>
```

I guess I don't understand round correctly, the type it wants for the first arg...

```
dvdb=> select round(123.456,1);
 round 
-------
 123.5
(1 row)

dvdb=> select round(cast(123.456 as float),1);
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select round(cast(123.456 as float),1);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
dvdb=>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it...

```
dvdb=> select round(cast(extract(epoch from age(end_dt,start_dt)/3600) as numeric),1) from delme;
 round 
-------
  60.6
(1 row)
```